# save different matrix in loop for matlab

Tags: image, signal-processing, matlab

I have a loop which iterates 20 time and produce matrix "A". I want to use a command to produce the results as A_1, A_2,..., A_20. How I should this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing what you need. The more effortless is probably

```
  save([MyOutput,int2str(i)], 'A'); %where i is your iteration index, 
                                    %thus you will have 20 different files.
```

or

```
  save(MyOutput, 'A','-append'); %which generates one file in which 
                                 %all your matrices are stored consequently.
```

But really there are million ways. Try to be more specific about what you need.

---

If you just need to use the matrices in your workspace you may consider using cells.

```
N = 20;
A_t = cell(N,1);

%in cycle
for ...
A_t(i) = {A};


Now your `A_t{i}` (note different parenthesis) is a cell containing your `A_i`.
```

Comment: what should I do if I do not want to save them and just produce A_1 ...A_20 in the workspace??

Comment: your codes are good Acorbe, but I do not want to save my matrixes. I just want to see them in my workspace with the name of A_1, A_2,...A_20

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use cell arrays you might consider the following:

`A = zeros(nrow,ncols,20)`

which will create a matrix `A` of dimension `nrow*ncol*20`. Always allocate the space for a large matrix in advance, don't built it plane by plane inside a loop. And replace `nrow` and `ncol` with whatever you want.  Then

```
for i = 1:20
    A(:,:,i) = ... stuff ...
end
```

and now you have a single 3D matrix called `A`.